# TCP Client PCL - How to send and receive from server?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

I'm using this library here: [sockets-for-pcl](https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl).

***Why do you use this library?***

To make communication with xamarin android and WPF desktop. (bidirectional / duplex communication).

The following code works great:

**Server:**

```
var listenPort = 11000;
var listener = new TcpSocketListener();

// when we get connections, read byte-by-byte from the socket's read stream
listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) => 
{
    var client = args.SocketClient; 

    var bytesRead = -1;
    var buf = new byte[1];

    while (bytesRead != 0)
    {
        bytesRead = await args.SocketClient.ReadStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, 1);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
            Debug.Write(buf[0]);
    }
};

// bind to the listen port across all interfaces
await listener.StartListeningAsync(listenPort);
```

**Client:**

```
var address = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 11000;
var r = new Random(); 

var client = new TcpSocketClient();
await client.ConnectAsync(address, port);

// we're connected!
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
    // write to the 'WriteStream' property of the socket client to send data
    var nextByte = (byte) r.Next(0,254);
    client.WriteStream.WriteByte(nextByte);
    await client.WriteStream.FlushAsync();

    // wait a little before sending the next bit of data
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)); 
}

await client.DisconnectAsync();
```

I need a code example for (bidirectional / duplex communication).

The client sends data to the server and receives the data from the server.

Comment: I hate all the communication sample code I've seen because there is no real application layer that sends commands and processes responses.  Get a good communications book to fully understand the application layer.  A client is the master which sends commands and the server is a slave that processes commands and send responses.  Servers are slaves and should never send a response without getting a command.  So you should modify code so client sends and then waits for response.  Server should wait for a command, process command, and then send response.

Comment: "In the Client code, I need to send values to Server", you already did that here `client.WriteStream.WriteByte(nextByte);` So probably need to explain better what you are trying to accomplish that the code doesn't.

Comment: @AaronLS, To send to server works, what I need is return.

Comment: Example: Client send value > Server receive > Server send value > Client receive value

Comment: @MatheusMiranda That's called bidirectional TCP, you might find some examples among these: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+bidirectional+tcp+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @AaronLS, Thanks for the `bi-directional TCP` word, it looks like this library does not have it.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda The builtin .NET TcpListener supports bidirectional/duplex communication

Comment: @AaronLS, It may be a way to follow the path, I just need to convert to `async`, I will see your documentation.

Comment: Was that the link you meant? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Yep, and note your library references claims it supports bi-directional communication on this page in the table: https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl

Comment: I'm angry, .NET TcpClient does not work with xamarin android. The right path is the "sockets-for-pcl" library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this test case, and look at the method `TcpSocketClient_ShouldSendReceiveDataSimultaneously`:

https://github.com/rdavisau/sockets-for-pcl/blob/dev/Sockets/Tests/Sockets.Tests/TcpSocketClientTests.cs

This method demonstrates bidirectional communication.  It is a little confusing because it is creating 2 pairs of connections, a listener for each, so it is acting as both a client and server.  You could easily split this out into separate client and server code.

In truth after the connection is established, client and server are essentially identical.  Either can be the listener.  In push notification scenarios for example, the client is the listener rather than server.

They setup the server socket first, because the server has to be waiting for a connection in order for a client connection attempt to succeed:

```
listener = new TcpSocketListener();
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ITcpSocketClient>();         
await listener.StartListeningAsync(port);
listener.ConnectionReceived += (sender, args) => tcs.SetResult(args.SocketClient);
```

Then the client attempt to connect using a different socket object:

```
socket1 = new TcpSocketClient();
await socket1.ConnectAsync("127.0.0.1", port);
```

It's a little confusing the way the test method is setup because it has both the server and client sockets in one method, but the key piece that kicks off the duplex sending/receiving is here, and you can see there's both sending and receiving occurring on both sockets.  You probably wouldn't use `WhenAll` in this way, they are doing it this way just to accomplish their testing, but the point is you can clearly see 2 pairs of send/receive results for both directions:

```
// let the sockets run for 2.5 seconds
var socketRunners =
  Task.WhenAll(
    Task.Run(() => sendAndReceive(socket1, sentToSocket2, recvdBySocket1, new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5)).Token).ContinueWith(t=> Debug.WriteLine($"Socket 1 task completed: {t}"))),
    Task.Run(() => sendAndReceive(socket2, sentToSocket1, recvdBySocket2, new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5)).Token).ContinueWith(t => Debug.WriteLine($"Socket 2 task completed: {t}")))
  );
```

Inside `sendAndReceive` is where the magic is happening.  Notice it is being run in parallel twice above, once for socket1, and once for socket2.  So both sockets are sending and receiving at the same time.  Inside `sendAndReceive` two tasks are started, one that is constantly writing, and one that is constantly reading(or receiving).  So you have two sendAndReceive tasks running with each starting 2 tasks(a read and a write).  Essentially 4 things happening in parallel:  Socket 1 reading, socket 1 writing, socket 2 reading, socket 2 writing.

```
var send = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var buf = new byte[1000];
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        r.NextBytes(buf);
        sent.AddRange(buf);
        await socket.WriteStream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, token);
        await socket.WriteStream.FlushAsync(token);
    }
});

var recv = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var buf = new byte[1000];
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var len = await socket.ReadStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, token);
        recvd.AddRange(buf.Take(len));
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm very confused, I do not understand what the `token` does.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda That's something used by many async handlers, it's a way for the caller of the async method to advise something when to cancel, since many async tasks can run forever. For example these tasks are infinite loops.  Passing `new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5)).Token` is a way to tell the async method to cancel after 2.5 seconds, and you'll notice the loop condition `while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)` as well as passing the token down into inner async calls like WriteAsync, so that at any point when `IsCancellationRequested==true` will stop the async task.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Some of the patterns here are really just for the sake of them automating their tests.  It proves duplex communication is possible, but I wouldn't copy it all line for line.  You might do your ReadStream as a task like this, as that makes sense since you're always waiting for data, but you'd probably put Write in a method you call on demand instead of an infinite loop.  You'd probably be serializing some objects, for example I use protobuf when sending over TCP, so I'd probably have some wrappers around these methods wiring the protobuf output stream to the TCP write stream.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  As I explained in the answer, the code in that test case creates two sockets, one to represent the client, and one to represent the server, it then uses the loop back IP address to connect the server socket to the client.  It sends data between the two sockets in both directions, then verifies the data that's been sent.

Comment: @AaronsSL, I almost solved the problem, I asked another question here, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308584/receiving-multiple-values-in-string

Comment: Worked to send and receive grace your response. There is a problem, the client receives multiple values.